# flask image classification ML model API implementation

Tags: python, api, machine-learning, flask

I try to implement a API for pre-trained resnet(machine learning model). so server can accepts a single valid image file in the request to be analyzed. Returns the output from running the image against the model.

I'm wondering what's the general structure of my api look like. So far I have

app
   api
      **init**.py (for blueprint)
      errors.py (for exceptions)
   main
     resnet18.py (for actual model and pic classification)

In my resnet18.py:

```
import torchvision.models as models
import torch
from torchvision import transforms


resnet18 = models.resnet18(pretrained=True)

transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(256),                           # resize the image to 256*256
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),                       # crop the image to 224*224 pixels about the center
    transforms.ToTensor(),                            # convert the image to PyTorch Tensor data type
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],  # Normalize the image by setting its mean and standard deviation to the specified values
                         std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])

])

from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('dog.jpg')

img_t = transform(img)
batch_t = torch.unsqueeze(img_t, 0)


out = resnet18(batch_t)


with open('imagenet_classes.txt') as f:
    classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

_, index = torch.max(out, 1)
percentage = torch.nn.functional.softmax(out, dim=1)[0] * 100

# print(classes[index[0]], percentage[index[0]].item())
most_likely = classes[index[0]]
confidence = percentage[index[0]].item()

# _, indices = torch.sort(out, descending=True)
# [(classes[idx], percentage[idx].item()) for idx in indices[0][:5]]

def to_json():
    json_prediction = {
        'most_likely': most_likely,
        'confidence': confidence
    }
    return json_prediction
```

So i want to call this fill once i upload a image. I'm wondering how can i make it more elegant. I never done anything like this.

Comment: can somebody provide a possible file structure as well?

Comment: A general rule of thumb: Any logic not in the main script should be put into functions and called from the main script when required.

Comment: I know that. I put this in main folder, which is at the same level as api folder. I'm not sure how to organize this file